# Excel VBA: Search folder and sub-directories for file excluding some sub-directories

Tags: vba, excel

I have found some code on line that searches a directory and it's sub-directories for a file meeting the search criteria.

I would like to edit this code to:

1. Stop after the first matching file is found
2. Ignore all sub-directories with "History" in it's name ('History', 'history' etc.)

The person who has created the directory structure has used spaces in the filenames, so examples of folders to ignore include "Tool History", all sub-directories in "Tool History"

The code I have found is below (sorry for not referencing source, I can't remember where I found it)

```
Function RecursiveDir(colFiles As Collection, _
                             strFolder As String, _
                             strFileSpec As String, _
                             bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    ' Search a folder and each of its subfolders for any files that meet the citerion given in
    ' strFileSpec

    ' colFiles - the name of the collection to add the output to
    ' strFolder - The path to the parent directory
    ' strFileSpec - The condition of the filename being searched for (for example all pdf files)
    ' bIncludeSubfolders - Boolean, include all subfolders in the search

    ' THIS FUNCTION IS SUBOPTIMAL AND VERY SLOW, PLEASE REVISIT IF USED REGULARLY

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant

    'Add files in strFolder matching strFileSpec to colFiles
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
        colFiles.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Fill colFolders with list of subdirectories of strFolder
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop

        'Call RecursiveDir for each subfolder in colFolders
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call RecursiveDir(colFiles, strFolder & vFolderName, strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

End Function

Function TrailingSlash(strFolder As String) As String
    ' Search for and remove a trailing slash in the directory pathname
    If Len(strFolder) > 0 Then
        If Right(strFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = strFolder
        Else
            TrailingSlash = strFolder & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This code is very slow, so if anyone has anything faster I would be truly grateful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do it like this.

```
Sub ListFilesInFolders()

Range("A:C").ClearContents
Range("A1").Value = "Folder Name"
Range("B1").Value = "File Name"
Range("C1").Value = "File Short Path"
Range("D1").Value = "File Type"
Range("A1").Select

Dim strPath As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long



'strPath = "C:\Data Collection\"
strPath = GetFolder

Dim OBJ As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object

Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder

MsgBox ("DONE!!!")
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

If Folder Like "*History*" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
r = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
For Each File In Folder.Files

        .Cells(r, 1).Value = File.ParentFolder
        .Cells(r, 2).Value = File.ShortName
        .Cells(r, 3).Value = File.ShortPath
        .Cells(r, 4).Value = File.Type

r = r + 1
Next File

End With

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
Next FolderItem

End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou, this lists all files in all sub-directories that don't have 'History' in their name. Great! Now suppose I want to update this code to only list files whose name is "*test.pdf", how would I do that?